# Foundation Menu button not switching classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu, zurb-foundation

I'm working on converting an existing mobile menu to AMP but noticed that the functionality without AMP is behaving strangely, (note that this is not a question about amp, in fact the amp for this menu and button is functioning correctly).

So the desired functionality is you click the hamburger, it then switches its class and morphs into a cross and the menu is shown. When the cross is clicked the button morphs back to a hamburger and the menu is hidden.

However what is happening is the first time the hamburger is clicked it shows the menu and changes the hamburger to a cross as expected but then when the cross is clicked the menu is hidden but the button remains a cross, clicking the button again will open the menu but the button is now a hamburger. So in effect the menu is working with each click but the button is changing on every 2 clicks.

The site is using wordpress if that matters. Following is a simplified version of the html rendered during each button click. First after page load:

```
    <a type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle offcanvas__menu__toggle" data-toggle="offCanvas" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="offCanvas">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </a>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right is-transition-overlap is-closed" id="offCanvas" style="top:62px" data-off-canvas="ji0gvo-off-canvas" data-transition="overlap" aria-hidden="false">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </div>
```

After the first click:

```
    <a type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle offcanvas__menu__toggle active" data-toggle="offCanvas" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="offCanvas">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </a>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right is-transition-overlap is-open" id="offCanvas" style="top:62px" data-off-canvas="ji0gvo-off-canvas" data-transition="overlap" aria-hidden="false">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </div>
```

After the second click:

```
    <a type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle offcanvas__menu__toggle active" data-toggle="offCanvas" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="offCanvas">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </a>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right is-transition-overlap is-closed" id="offCanvas" style="top:62px" data-off-canvas="ji0gvo-off-canvas" data-transition="overlap" aria-hidden="false">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </div>
```

After the third click:

```
    <a type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle offcanvas__menu__toggle" data-toggle="offCanvas" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="offCanvas">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </a>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right is-transition-overlap is-open" id="offCanvas" style="top:62px" data-off-canvas="ji0gvo-off-canvas" data-transition="overlap" aria-hidden="false">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </div>
```

After the fourth click:

```
    <a type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle offcanvas__menu__toggle active" data-toggle="offCanvas" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="offCanvas">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </a>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right is-transition-overlap is-closed" id="offCanvas" style="top:62px" data-off-canvas="ji0gvo-off-canvas" data-transition="overlap" aria-hidden="false">
        {content removed for brevity}
    </div>
```

Hopefully from the above you can see the pattern. I have to click the menu button twice to toggle the button animations but the menu itself is showing and hiding with each click.

my `$(document).foundation()` is like this with no options

So does anybody have any ideas what could be stopping the class in the burger button from switching correctly?

Is there another way I *should* be doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end the mobile menu was redisgned and the issue stopped.